# Custom Logback Appender doesn't catch log events

Tags: logging, aem, logback, sling, appender

I'm writing my own logging appender for AEM 6
I've found an [example](https://github.com/chetanmeh/sling-logback/blob/master/example/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/examples/logback/FilteringAppender.java) at `sling-logback` repo, and have tried to apply it to my project.

I configured it for `com.company:DEBUG` and removed filtering logic from the example
Code snippet is [here](https://gist.github.com/dkBrazz/bafaeb61f6b770a9bf6a28d14bc650f9)

When the bundle is installed, I see that it is registered as an Appender at the `/system/console/slinglog`. (In the Logger section I see the only file appenders, should I see there my Custom one?)
But logback doesn't send log-events to my appender.
I have no non-additive appenders configured for this logging path

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `:DEBUG` suffix mentioned in the official example is deprecated.

The solution is to use just `com.company` logger name
And there is no way to assign loglevel for logger-appender pair